# Manually Backup FileZilla ftp details if FileZilla got Corrupted

Tags: ftp, backup, filezilla, manual, corrupt

If FileZilla got Corrupted Somehow. So how to backup manually the existing ftp details that are been with filezilla ?? So that i can use the details after i re-install the fresh filezilla copy.

Answer (score 2):

Just backup the directory

Win: %APPDATA%\FileZilla   {*Type "%APPDATA%\FileZilla" in RUN*}
Linux, Mac, other: ~/.filezilla

Once You install the Fresh Copy of filezilla just replace the new created folder with the backed-up one, or Open FileZilla after install and click File > Import > Navigate to backup filezilla folder and select the file named "**sitemanager.xml**" > click ok

& Enjoy ;)